# Where can I learn more about how to structure an MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I realise this might be a little vague but I honestly don't know where else to ask. I have some history with PHP and I am trying to teach myself ASP.NET MVC3.

While I can find a LOT of source material on syntax and tutorials on various parts. I've started it off and I've got quite a bit going but I'm finding it a bit difficult to figure out exactly how to design the whole thing with regards to where to put things and I'm not entirely certain who I can ask or where I can find these things out?

The project I'm working on, in an attempt to teach myself is a form of online rpg game site. I've got user registration and log in, I wrote a custom membership provider to fit that to my existing database structure. But the trouble I'm having knowing where to do database lookups and how to store data etc. For example, let's say you log in, you have a certain amount of gold. On the right side of the status bar on the _layout page it will always display this value. Where do you look this up? How do you remember it? In the controller? Which controller? Etc etc.

Can anyone maybe recommend either a good set of advanced tutorials or some kind of forum where this can be discussed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN and ASP.NET sites have a LOT to offer on MVC3.  I would also suggest buying the two MVC3 books by Phil Haack and Steve Sanderson.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/overview/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/17/asp-net-mvc-3-roundup-of-tutorials-videos-labs-and-other-assorted-training-materials.aspx

Those are all good links and tutorials.  In addition, you are going to want to have a separate database for your data vs. your Authentication and Authorization.  This will allow decoupling and better security.  You should be storing data in a database, and then the model will hold access to that database through a DAL (Data Access Layer) usually with the controller holding an instantiated repository of the DAL.  In this sense the controller can build objects from the model (and thereby from the database) and then send them to the view through strongly typed objects for you to use in a User Interface.

Answer (score 3):

I learned everything i know from:

- [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
- [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) -> awesome blog entries on mvc 3
- Must see the [Music Store Tutorial App](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1)

Answer (score 3):

Check out a great book by Steve Sanderson - Ive used the previous two editions to get me upto speed with MVC.

[Pro ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-3rd/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325187950&sr=1-1)

If your looking to use Entity Framework then I can also recommend;

[Programming Entity Framework](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Entity-Framework-Julia-Lerman/dp/0596807260/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325188360&sr=1-1)

Answer (score 1):

**Nerd Dinner** is a pretty good sample of the whole picture, you can download the sample code and play with it.

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have done the Nerd Dinner tutorial, it was expanding on it that stumbled me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

The problem I find is a lot of examples don't use best practices for MVC in favour of simplicity and ease of reading in tutorials. So I'll outline some of the things I've found out the hard way and that work for me.

Personally from what I've found is your controller should be responsible for handling information via ViewModels to act as Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) between your business logic and your views, and that's all they should have in them. I choose to never have business logic in the controller and instead opt for a series of service classes designed to deal with their own group of responsibilities (IoC takes care of most concerns the Services may have).
This is done to keep the business logic DRY and to make it easier should you decide to try making a mobile version of your site later, or maybe expose a public WebService/API to your data.

The views should each use ViewModels specifically meant for each view, and these views should ONLY consist of primitive types or other view models. Never use a data entity from your ORM directly, though I'll be honest I have been known to break my own rule on this when it comes to views that only display information, but I usually pay for it later. Validation rules imposed on your data model are not necessarily applicable to a form and data loaded on your entity may not be relevant to your view either. ORM's that support Lazy Loading complex data entities can cause havoc with some VERY useful 3rd party libraries you can use in MVC like [MiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) and [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/), not to mention other issues when it comes to rendering these objects in forms for posting back later. So try to stick to flat ViewModels if possible.

I typically name my ViewModels according to their use. so my Register page may use a model called `AccountsRegisterViewModel`. However when I postback I usually use a different model called `AccountsRegisterFormModel`. This is because many times there is information I need to pass to render in the view but I really don't care about it (nor will it be present in most cases) on the action that accepts my postback. Also, MVC requires you to disambiguate your actions that use the same name via different parameters so using different view models helps there. For example `CreateAccount()` to show the account creation page and `CreateAccount()` that accepts your submission from the form. Though you can explicitly change where each form posts, the main focus with MVC is convention over configuration so I try not to change where forms post back to.

For your specific example of showing relevant information (Gold balance) you're likely going to want to create a Child Action with it's own view that would be responsible for doing it's own data access, or if you want to try your hand at ajax, have the balance be something handled in a smiple partial view that makes a call to a public action that returns JSON.

Those are the practices I've found have worked for me so far.

Comment: Thanks you so much, this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for.